# XCode 8.1 Update Frames not working

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

As I understand, there used to be an update frames button and since 8.1 it has been removed and replaced with a refresh page looking button. Also, you can go and click on editor and find the update frames there. HOWEVER, whenever I try clicking any of these things nothing happens, it doesn't go to the constraints I specified. Has anyone encountered this before?

Update: I hit size to fit content and it shrinks it size but I'm not sure what it means as compared to updating the frames. Ultimately, I just want my images to be smaller so I can see what they look like if I were to run the game on the simulator. Thanks

Comment: Whenever you select update frame, autolayout functionality is update that in itself way. so you need to remove constraint and add again.

Comment: I don't know if this is a solution or not but I accidentally hit size to fit content and that seemingly did what I wanted. Do you know what that is?

Comment: can you explain your question with more explaination. i thnk i missing some understand about your question

Comment: use layout if needed

Answer (score 0):

Try this....

@IBOutlet weak var myConstraints: NSLayoutConstraint!

@IBAction doChangeFrame(sender: AnyObject) 
{

```
 myPropoLeftEdgeConstraint.constant = view.frame.width
 view.layoutIfNeeded()
```

}